# Why is the product search filter not working in the Thinking in React tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJs and started following the tutorial on the official documentation. For some reason, the search filter text box after step4 seems to be read only. It is not taking in any text I entered. What is the issue here?

Here is the link to the tutorial
 - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

It seems like there is some issue with the way SearchBar is rendered. But I can't figure out what it is.

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value{this.props.filterText}/>
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.inStockOnly} />
          {' '}
          Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/zafjbw1e/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=zafjbw1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [step 5](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow) they show you why that don't work. They to this with a function inside the onChange. Remember: React is all about one-way data flow down the component hierarchy. So the props you pass to your component are coming from the parent. If you read further they teach you how the flow work. ;)

Hope that can help ;)

PS that was read only cause the value props is an empty string ;) And because you don't push to the top new state you don't change it.

```
var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      filterText: '', // HERE AM EMPTY AND YOU DONT PASS NEW STATE SO I STAY EMPTY
      inStockOnly: false
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
        />
        <ProductTable
          products={this.props.products}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is a so-called [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) .Put simply ,the value inside the input bar is controlled be `value` property of `<input>` element ,thus you can only change the value by setting the `value` property  ,
try to change
 `value={this.props.filterText}` 
to
 `value={"aa"}` 
you will know what I mean.Just keep following the tutorial , everything should be fine